# Faster calculation of cumulative sum in attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, performance, expression, summarizing

I have a shapefile attribute table in QGIS that I would like to calculate the cumulative sum. The thing is that it has over 1.5 million features.

Type of device: HDD.

The attribute table looks like this:

[image]

I have tried to calculate in a new field the cumulated sum for `"Equitativo"` like this:

```
 with_variable(
    'ID_FINAL',
    ID_FINAL,
    sum(Equitativo, filter:=ID_FINAL<=@ID_FINAL)
    )
```

The problem is that is taking way too long (it's running for 17 hours now). How could I make this faster way?

Comment: Full table scans take time. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the storage format of the data, the type of device on which it is stored, and the actual runtime in seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure what "type of device" means.

Comment: HDD, SSD, USB thumb drive,...

Comment: If you need to perform many calculations like this you can use geopandas. The calculation is performed in less than a second. But it takes about 30 s to read the shapefile and the same to write

Comment: @BERA (geo)pandas is really so fast. but it took 76 seconds to read, 0.02 second to sum (insanely  fast), 127 seconds to write to file in my computer.

Comment: Yes, only worth it if there are multiple calculations to be done

Answer (score 15):

You can use the script below in QGIS [Python Editor](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html#the-code-editor). It takes about 45 seconds (including saving to the source file) for 1.5 million features in SSD or HDD. Select the layer first.

```py
import time
from qgis.gui import QgsRubbersBand
from qgis.gui import iface
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qvariant

start time = time.time()

layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Add CUM_SUM field if not exist
field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("CUM_SUM")
if field_index == -1:
    field = QgsField('CUM_SUM', QVariant.Double, len=20, prec=3)
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([field])
    layer.updateFields()

# Get field indices
id_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("ID_FINAL")
eq_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("Equitativo")
cum_sum_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("CUM_SUM")

cum_sum = 0
attribute_map = {}
request = QgsFeatureRequest().addOrderBy('ID_FINAL').setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry).setSubsetOfAttributes(['ID_FINAL', 'Equitativo'], layer.fields())
for feature in layer.getFeatures(request):
    cum_sum += feature["Equitativo"]
    attribute_map.update({feature.id(): {cum_sum_index: cum_sum}})

layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attribute_map)

print("%s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why this Python skript is so much faster?

Comment: @Babel It is hard to me to explain such a thing in English. Nyall Dawson explains "[How to speed up PyQGIS scripts](https://nyalldawson.net/2016/10/speeding-up-your-pyqgis-scripts/)". It can give you an idea why an expression is sometimes so slow. For example; using `get_feature_by_id` is one of the reasons. Behind the scene, QGIS needs to do a bunch of things to give you the matching feature.

Comment: @Babel. Nyall says: *Well, remember that every time you call getFeatures() QGIS needs to do a whole bunch of things before it can start giving you the matching features. In this case, the code is calling getFeatures() once **for every feature** ID in the list. So if the list had 100 features, that means QGIS is having to create a connection to the data source, set up and prepare a query to match a single feature, wait for the provider to process that, and then finally parse the single feature result. That’s a lot of wasted processing!*

Comment: An expression may include that kind of situations. @Babel

Comment: That makes sense, thanks a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Your expression is not efficient because it calculates the same sum over and over again: for feature no. 100, it is adding 100 numbers (feature1, feature2, ... feature100), even though adding 99% of these values (from feature1 to feature99) was done before.

Better rely on the already calculated sum of the last feature: for feature 100, something like (pseudocode):
`sum (feature100) = sum (feature99) + value (feature100)`

So try this expression:

```
attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer, $id), 'Equitativo')
+
attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer, $id-1), 'Equitativo')
```

Will definitely take more time than the [Python script by @Kadir Şahbaz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/421205/88814), so you might want to stick to this. This solution here is just to show how to do it using QGIS expressions only.

Comment: +1. A small issue here: We don't know if the table is ordered by `ID_FINAL`. Its order may not be matched with `$id` order. Is that possible to order by `ID_FINAL` using expression before running it?

Comment: Indeed, this works if the order for cumulative sum is the same than `$id`. If not, this would complicate things and I would definitely not stick to using expressions for larger datasets as your Python skript is much more efficient.